# how to redirect a url after a login in webview android

Tags: android, redirect, webview

i am trying to redirect the user to a other specified url after a succesful login how can i do it ?

```
public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("academia.srmuniv.ac.in")) {
        return false;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always return `false` in  `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` function.
Otherwise it dosen't work in some android 6 mobiles .

Change return `true` to return `false` at the end of function .